# CSS tranform:translateY from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, transform

How would I access and change `transform: translateY(0px);` using the style object from JavaScript, in a similar matter to `div.style.background = 50px`.

I'm trying to make it so a header on my webpage disappears as the user scrolls down but
`div.style.tranform` or `div.style.translate` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can pass any transform property as a string.

HOW?

It can be done like this;

```
div.style.transform = "translate(x,y)"
```

I find out that if I write

```
div.style.transform = "translate(someValue)"
```

It only affects x axes.

```
"translate-y(someValue)" or "translate-x(someValue)"
```

did not work out.

Or you can use rotate property;

```
div.style.transform = "rotate(50px)".
```

Try it!

https://jsfiddle.net/araknafobia/4wtxu0dr/1/

Comment: div.style.transform = "translateY(someValue)"

Comment: In my case, my mistake was to forget the unit of `someValue`. Instead of `translate(10)`, write `translate(10px)` for example.

Comment: Not working for me for some reason, it does not let me change transform style in any way.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to the accepted answer, it is also possible to target the each axis separately - such as in the following example:

```
div.style.transform = "translateY(10px)";
```

Again, the value in the parentheses can be anything that would otherwise work when specified directly in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go through style.transform to achieve a *translation*

[translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate) can stand by itself, making the code less verbose e.g.

- CSS : `translate: 0px 50px;`
- JS  : `div.style.translate = '0px 50px';`

[Example on codepen](https://codepen.io/Steffen-Dyhr-Nielsen/pen/GRwqxox)

Answer (score 0):

As an added note to endertunc's answer, if you're having trouble with the transform style not changing despite the JavaScript code being called, it's most likely the string's internal syntax as it is VERY sensitive. For example:

```
/* ----- JavaScript Style Property ----- */

// First argument is for X, second is for Y; this works:
div.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';

// However, this does NOT work [note the whitespace between 'translate' and '(...']:
div.style.transform = 'translate (-50%, -50%)';
```

Another common grammatical syntax slip-up I found is forgetting or overlooking simple punctuation like a comma. As another example:

```
// This works, outputs accordingly:
div.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';

// This does NOT work, but you'll get no error feedback upon inspecting the DOM:
// (psst...we are missing the comma between the X and Y of translate!)
div.style.transform = 'translate(-50% -50%)';
```

If you are wondering why all of this is happening, the best explanation I can give stems from MDN's web docs where they mention that the style string is to be processed and forwarded to the CSSStyleDeclaration object, which must be silently "dropping" or ignoring the string if it wasn't what it was expecting in terms of parsed syntax. You can find what I am referring to on MDN at this link: [MDN Web Docs: HTMLElement: style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Hopefully this helps!