# Modifying values in a transform style

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I have a variable called `transformstyle` which returns me the transformation style of another element.
For example: `console.log(transformstyle);` would return `translate(155%, -259%) scale(0.6)`

I want to make modifications to the transformation, for example I want to do `translate(155% + 30%, -259% - 115%);`

How can I access the interior of the transformation to make these changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS tranform:translateY from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707991/css-tranformtranslatey-from-javascript)

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya this is nothing alike to what I am asking mate.

Comment: @evilgenious448  Ok can you show us the code of how this fantastic variable came about or we just going to work extra hard and write everything from scratch?

Comment: All you have here is a plain text string, it is not an object that had any methods or properties to access the individual values - you will have to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do some hack like this.

```js
var s = "translate(155%, -259%)";  /*transformstyle*/ 

s = s.replace(/[()]/g,",");
s = s.replace(/[%]/g,""); 

var x = Number(s.split(",")[1]); 
var y = Number(s.split(",")[2]);

var newX = 30;
var newY = -115;

var newTransformstyle = 'translate('+(x+newX)+'%,' +(y+newY)+'%)';

console.log(newTransformstyle);
```